# Integrate Bootstrap theme with Laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have worked on Laravel and Bootstrap and learnt the basics of both of them. I would like to know how to integrate a Bootstrap theme into the Laravel project so that I can use that for my project. Right now, I have a scratch Laravel folder along with the downloaded theme. How do I proceed with this? I am getting started with some minor projects on Laravel. Appreciate if someone can help me out or link me to videos that show me how to do this.

Answer (score 10):

You should put your assets (css, js, etc) inside your public folder since files inside that folder should always be accessible to the "public".

An example project could look like this:

[image: Example of bootstrap in laravel]

Next you can insert these files in your HTML by using hard coded paths like:

```
<script src="/path/to/file"></script>
```

Or you can use the `asset()` helper function (more preferable):

```
<script src="<?php echo asset(/path/to/file); ?>"></script>
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on a Laravel project where I had to get a theme from [bootswatch.com](http://bootswatch.com), Darkly to be specific.

I included the theme using a cdn as follows,

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.0/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-J01jr7rrJqxij+hUE1E+8N35mlD7L/TMrAO7tOarwMP7AWJM3P/lGXOjt0KLNhtE" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
```

But the theme didn't take effect until I **removed** the following line which is importing the default css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```